# How can I inspect params and stop requisition in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I starting study Rails 4, and I want see something, just curiously.

I want see all params sent with a form (post).

I try that:

```
def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    article_params.inspect
    ..
    ..
    ..
end
```

But the create process continued, and I not saw the params inspected.

And, in *rails console*, the callback is:

```
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-25 11:00:53 -0300
[2013-09-25 11:00:53] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

So, I want STOP the requisition, like exit() in php.

**OR, what the correctly way to do that in Rails?**

How can I do that? (I'm just study, is not an error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
 return render text => article_params.to_yaml
```

Another option is use the debugger gem, which allows you a full inspect, but in the console, not in the browser.

Comment: undefined local variable or method `text' for #<ArticlesController:0x3f915d8>

Answer (score 1):

As said above me. The debugger gem would be really useful here.

https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger

Just add it to your gemfile `gem 'debugger'`

From there when you are in the file you want to debug just require it at the top, `require 'debugger'`, and call it wherever you want by just calling `debugger`. I would suggest putting it where you wanted `article_params.inspect` to be. When the code gets to the debugger your program will be in debugger mode which will then allow you to do things such as determine what is in that array.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following this will stop requisition, like exit() in php.

```
raise article_params.inspect # or raise params.inspect
```